# reading a csv file from azure blob storage with PySpark

Tags: azure, apache-spark, pyspark, azure-storage, azure-hdinsight

I'm trying to do a machine learning project using a PySpark HDInsight cluster on Microsoft Azure. To operate on my cluster a use a Jupyter notebook. Also, I have my data (a csv file), stored on the Azure Blob storage.

According to the documentation the syntax of the path to my file is:

```
path = 'wasb[s]://springboard@6zpbt6muaorgs.blob.core.windows.net/movies_plus_genre_info_2.csv'
```

However, when i try to read the csv file with the following command:

```
csvFile = spark.read.csv(path, header=True, inferSchema=True)
```

I get the following error:

```
'java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in scheme name at index 4: wasb[s]://springboard@6zpbt6muaorgs.blob.core.windows.net/movies_plus_genre_info_2.csv'
```

Here is a screenshot of the the error looks like in the notebook:
[image: error screenshot]

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: It is either wasb:// or wasbs://. wasbs is the secure version of wasb

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is either (unencrypted):

```
wasb://...
```

or (encrypted):

```
wasbs://...
```

not

```
wasb[s]://...
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That fixed the problem !